# Download all Wordpress.com available themes, somewhere?

Tags: themes, wordpress.com-hosting, list

I am looking for a website, or a way to find and download all Wordpress.com available themes for my WPMU website. I have searched for some on http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/ but they don't seem to be there.

So do you know any repo or list with those themes listed and links to download them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can from now on download all [free themes on wordpress.com](http://theme.wordpress.com/themes/sort/free/). On theme's page look for "Download [name] for your self-hosted WordPress site" link in sidebar, under "Stats & Info".

Konstantin Obenland announced that in [a tweet today](https://twitter.com/obenland/status/361221608653856768).

Comment: There is also this, which will keep your .com themes up-to-date too: http://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpresscom-theme-updates/

Answer (score 1):

WordPress.com is not open source project.

- *some* of [their themes are available in repository](http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/profile/automattic)
- some are based on open source themes by others
- some are versions of third party commercial themes

But overall they do not provide their theme package for wordpress.org installations.